# Plot polar coordinate with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, coordinates

I am trying to plot points, not spirals (or lines), on a polar coordinate system using python (3.3) and matplotlib.  I have numpy and matplotlib installed. For example, the polar coordinate (4, pi/2)will look like a (0,4) on a Cartesian coordinate plane.

Comment: Given [matplotlib examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html), [the matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#pie_and_polar_charts) and the [pyplot manual on `polar()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.polar), what have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered

```
matplotlib.pyplot.polar(theta_array, r_array, 'k.')
```

as per [the manual](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.polar)?